# python check if empty string is in list

Tags: python, string, list

not a long ago I came across weird thing with `if '' in lst`.
The code bellow gives me output:

```
1 - yes
2 - no
3 - yes
```

Can you tell me why `1` is `yes`?

```
########################################
if '' in ('a'):
    print('1 - yes')
else:
    print('1 - no')


########################################
if '' in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
    print('2 - yes')
else:
    print('2 - no')


########################################
if '' in (''):
    print('3 - yes')
else:
    print('3 - no')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> print(type(('a')))
<class 'str'>
```

So you could realize what happened. `('a')` is automatically converted into a string, so `if '' in ('a')` equals `if '' in 'a'`, and an empty string is in every string.

Answer (score 4):

```
if '' in ('a'):
    print('1 - yes')
else:
    print('1 - no')
```

You are testing if the empty string is contained in the string `a`  since `('a')` is not a tuple, it's simply the string `'a'`. The empty string is always considered to be contained in any other non-empty string.

You should change `('a')` to `('a',)` if you want to create a tuple with only the string `'a'` in it.

Answer (score 4):

`('a')` is a string, simplifies to `'a'`, and all strings contain an empty string. If you made it a tuple then you'd get `False`, like `'' in ('a',)`.

Answer (score 3):

You should have done like this -

```
if '' in ('a',):
   print('1 - yes')
else:
   print('1 - no')
```

`('a')` is nothing but string `'a'` where `('a',)` is a tuple

Answer (score 2):

You can assume that:

```
'a' = '' + 'a' + ''
```

In the second example - '' is not an element of the list. The elements are 'a', 'b' and 'c'.

Answer (score 2):

`Empty strings` are always considered to be a `substring` of any other `string`.

```
>>> 'a'.find('')
0
```

It implies `''` is present in the `'a'`, so `'' in ('a')` is `True`